# Is there a way to automatically execute the 'Select' command on a GridView, when the Grid loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a GridView who's DataSource SELECTs based on the SelectedValue of another GridView.

On the GridView with the SelectedValue (DataKeyName), I need to execute the Select command when the grid loads, rather that using a "Select" button.

I've tried using the SelectedIndex attribute of the GridView but this wont do it for me.
I've also looked at various methods and events but I cant seem to find a good way of doing this.

In the code below, there is a ButtonField with a "Select" button but I would like the Select command to take place as or after the grid is populated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ClientDetailsGridView" runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AccountNumber" DataSourceID="ZeNetAccounts" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="749px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="More Information" Text="View" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountNumber" HeaderText="Account #" SortExpression="AccountNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountName" HeaderText="Client Name" SortExpression="AccountName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address1" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="PostalCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PrimaryPhoneNumberFormatted" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="PrimaryPhoneNumberFormatted" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="25px" CssClass="GridHeaderBasic" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="25px" CssClass="GridDataRows" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="25px" CssClass="GridDataRows" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="25px" CssClass="GridDataRows" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="25px" CssClass="GridDataRows" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="25px" CssClass="GridDataRows" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="25px" CssClass="GridDataRows" />
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="CustomFieldsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex="0" DataKeyNames="DocumentNumber,DocumentType,CustomFieldDefinitionKeyID" DataSourceID="ZeNetCustomFields">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentNumber" HeaderText="DocumentNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DocumentNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentType" HeaderText="DocumentType" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DocumentType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomFieldDefinitionKeyID" HeaderText="CustomFieldDefinitionKeyID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomFieldDefinitionKeyID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomFieldValue" HeaderText="CustomFieldValue" SortExpression="CustomFieldValue" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ZeNetAccounts" runat="Server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Ze-Net_Technologies %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblAccounts] WHERE ([AccountName] = @AccountName)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ClientSearch" Name="AccountName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ZeNetCustomFields" runat="Server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Ze-Net_Technologies %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblCustomFieldValues] WHERE ([DocumentNumber] = @DocumentNumber)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ClientDetailsGridView" Name="DocumentNumber" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the page load of your asp.net page?

Comment: I could but the grid with the SelectedValue has a DataSource that queries based on a Value from a Textbox, which runs a postback when the item in query is searched for. 
It gets sticky because there are 2 tables in the database that do not have a FK relationship but are related in the program its self, if that makes sense.
The Grid is only visible and populated when the TextBox runs a search.

Comment: I think you can call the [`SelectRow` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectrow(v=vs.110).aspx) of your GridView during the PostBack, although I'm not positive.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I can see how that would work.
Is there a way that I can fire this even after the gird had loaded? 
Would the RowCreated event work for this?

Comment: Well, I tried `    protected void ClientDetailsGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientDetailsGridView.SelectRow(0);
    }` but no change.

Comment: I'm confused, I think.  I thought you wanted to select a row in the CustomFieldsGridView based on the Button clicked in the ClientDetailsGridView.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I'm sorry. Well, the CustomFieldsGridView has a data source that is dependent on the selection from the ClientDetailsGridview. I would like to automate the 'Select' command on ClientDetailsGridView so that the data in CustomFieldsGridView appears automatically, rather than hitting a Select button (in the ClientDetailsGridView). The ClientDetailsGridView only has one row.